# Angular: Cloning ng-content elements and it's functionality

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to clone the `ng-content` items of a component along with any functionality added on the HTML of that content. For example, the markup using the component might look like this:

```
<custom-component>
  <button (click)="doAThing();">A button</button>
</custom-component>
```

Then I set up my template for custom-component like so:

```
<ng-template #content>
  <ng-conent></ng-content>
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-template>
<div class="second-area">
  <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-template>
</div>
```

My expectation would be that the `ng-content` would get duplicated into both `ngTemplateOutlet` areas. What happens is that it pushes to the last outlet and ignores the first. This markup will duplicate normal markup just fine, but ng-content only move to one outlet.

Is this not possible with this technique, am I missing something obvious, or it there another way to clone the contents of `ng-content` along with any events attached to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution that worked for me. First the HTML, you'll need a directive to wrap the content in so you can reference it. You'll need to use asterisk with directive so it can be duplicated.

```
<custom-component>
  <ng-container *customDirective>
    <button (click)="doAThing();">A button</button>
  </ng-container>
</custom-component>
```

The directive doesn't require any extra code. We just need it for a reference.

In your custom-component, you'll need to create a reference to the diretive via @ContentChild like so:

```
@ContentChild(CustomDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) transcludeTemplate;
```

Then we use the following for our custom-component HTML avoiding using `ng-content` tags all together:

```
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="transcludeTemplate"></ng-template>
<div class="second-area">
  <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="transcludeTemplate"></ng-template>
</div>
```

So this isn't really the same as duplicating `<ng-content>`, but it gives us a similar function. Apparently ng-content not multiplying is [intended behavior](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9173#issuecomment-225732419). So this might be the best way to achieve a similar goal.